# Do HTC widgets not work with ADWLauncher?

Tags: app-widgets, adw.launcher

I've just installed ADW.launcher, which is a lot cleaner than the original HTC Sense homescreen, but I can't seem to get my Clock/Weather widget back. It's not appearing in the list of widgets.

Is it just me, or do none of the HTC widgets work with ADW Launcher, or is it that the HTC widgets will only work with the HTC home screen?

Alternatively, is there a decent clock app that displays digital time, and maybe weather too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC Sense widgets do indeed only work with the Sense homescreen. There are knock-offs, but these are usually pulled off the market by HTC very quickly. Beautiful Widgets comes quite close though.

Comment: I've found a close second with Sense Analog Clock, but it's just not the same as the nice weather animations I used to get :(